# Indirect point cloud and image registration

Tags: registration

I converted the architectural point cloud into a 2D label image, and matched it with the color image. I have tried several mainstream methods, but the effect is not very good. Do have any suggestions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrukF.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKfRF.jpg)

I tried to extract line features in two images, and applied several line feature-based matching networks SOLD2 and LineTR.but not good

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.